# TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object python

Tags: python, if-statement, typeerror

I am creating a password validation system. However I have received an error message and i do not understand why or where the error is. I tested these individual pieces of validations on a separate files and they worked okay, however when they were implemented into my actual program, it seems to not work.
This is the code responsible for the validation.

```
#Ensures passwords match and writes the account details to the database
def Checker():
    if re.match(user_password2v2, user_passwordv2):
        match+=1
    else:
        match=match
    if len(user_namev2) > 5 and len(user_passwordv2)>7:#Ensures the username and passwor are of a minimum length
        match+=1
    else:
        match=match
    if re.search(r"\W", user_password2): #Ensures a character is present in the password
        match+=1
    else:
        match=match
    if re.search(r'[0-9]', user_weightv2):#Ensures numbers are used in the weight entry
        match+=1
    else:
        match=match
    if match==4:
        user_information.append(user_namev2)
        user_information.append(user_passwordv2)
        user_information.append(weight)
        Goal_Select()
    if match!=4:
        Error()
```

`Error()` should be ran if any of these conditional statements are not met.

`user_namev2`, `user_passwordv2` and `user_weightv2` are all variables which are pulled from tkinter entry boxes.

Here is a screenshot of my whole error message.
[image]

Comment: All of the `else` cases are pointless, just remove them. But you haven't shown how the function is called. What is `user_password2v2`? Why aren't you passing the values to the function instead of looking for them in the global scope? `match` also isn't defined.

Comment: You use `user_passwordv2` everywhere else but `user_password2` on that line (without the "v" at the end.) Naming the variables a bit better would help avoid mistakes like this.

Comment: Its a validation system for an account system. Userpassword2v2 represents the input for the confirm password entry box. This is only a snippet of the function as well, the full function defines match and the variables user_passwordv2, user_password2v2, user_weightv2 and user_namev2

Comment: Yes i thought the else statements were irrelevant. I originally had them removed but I added them back in to see if thats where the issue was stemming from

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Data type of 'user_passwordv2' doesn't look like to be suitable for `re.search`.
How about following code as type conversion?

```
re.search(r"\W", str(user_password2))
#re.search(r"\W", user_password2)
```

Comment: Yeah this seems to be the issue. Thank you!